# Need a different permutation of groups of numbers

Tags: mysql, sql, math, permutation

I have numbers from 1 to 36. What I am trying to do is put all these numbers into **three** groups and works out all various permutations of groups.

Each group must contain 12 numbers, from 1 to 36

A number cannot appear in more than one group, per permutation

Here is an example....

```
Permutation 1
Group 1: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12
Group 2: 13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24
Group 3: 25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36

Permutation 2
Group 1: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,13
Group 2: 12,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24
Group 3: 25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36

Permutation 3
Group 1: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,14
Group 2: 12,11,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24
Group 3: 25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36
```

Those are three example, I would expect there to be millions/billions more

Comment: Permutation is usually applied to a single set (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation).  Your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: To make your question clear, please give a simpler example and show us your complete desired result from that sample. Also give a more lengthy and detailed explanation in words. As it is now, your question makes no sense.

Comment: I think you're missing lots of information missing about the problem statement. I also think this would be more suitable with an "algorithm" tag.  Work out the algorithm first, then worry about how to deal with it in SQL.  I assume you mean that you want each possible combination of groups, such that for 2 groups, and numbers 1,2,3 the combinations would be [[1],[2,3]]  ,  [[1,2],[3]]  ,  [[3],[1,2]]  ,  [[1,2,3],[{empty}]]  ,  [[{empty}],[1,2,3]]

Comment: Ok ,I missed a few combinations, should be something like [[1],[2,3]]  , [[2],[1,3]] ,  [[3],[1,2]]  ,[[1,2],[3]], [[1,3],[2]], [2,3],[1]],  [[1,2,3],[{empty}]]  ,  [[{empty}],[1,2,3]]  

Begs the questions: Are empty sets allowed, are you looking for unique combinations (e.g. are [[3],[1,2]]  ,[[1,2],[3]] two different combinations) is ordering important within the groups?

Comment: Updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The analysis that follows assumes the order of groups matters - that is, if the numbers were 1, 2, 3 then the grouping [{1},{2},{3}] is distinct from the grouping [{3},{2},{1}] (indeed, there are six distinct groupings when taking from this set of numbers).

In your case, how do we proceed? Well, we must first choose the first group. There are 36 choose 12 ways to do this, or (36!)/[(12!)(24!)] = 1,251,677,700 ways. We must then choose the second group. There are 24 choose 12 ways to do this, or (24!)/[(12!)(12!)] = 2,704,156 ways. Since the second choice is already conditioned upon the first we may get the total number of ways of taking the three groups by multiplying the numbers; the total number of ways to choose three equal groups of 12 from a pool of 36 is 3,384,731,762,521,200. If you represented numbers using 8-bit bytes then to store every list would take at least ~3 pentabytes (well, I guess times the size of the list, which would be 36 bytes, so more like ~108 pentabytes). This is a lot of data and will take some time to generate and no small amount of disk space to store, so be aware of this.

To actually implement this is not so terrible. However, I think you are going to have undue difficulty implementing this in SQL, if it's possible at all. Pure SQL does not have operations that return more than n^2 entries (for a simple cross join) and so getting such huge numbers of results would require a large number of joins. Moreover, it does not strike me as possible to generalize the procedure since pure SQL has no ability to do general recursion and therefore cannot do a variable number of joins.

You could use a procedural language to generate the groupings and then write the groupings into a database. I don't know whether this is what you are after.

```
n = 36

group1[1...12] = []
group2[1...12] = []
group3[1...12] = []

function Choose(input[1...n], m, minIndex, group)

    if minIndex + m > n + 1 then
        return

    if m = 0 then

        if group = group1 then
            Choose(input[1...n], 12, 1, group2)

        else if group = group2 then
            group3[1...12] = input[1...12]
            print group1, group2, group3

    for i = i to n do

        group[12 - m + 1] = input[i]
        Choose(input[1 ... i - 1].input[i + 1 ... n], m - 1, i, group)
```

When you call this like `Choose([1...36], 12, 1, group1)` what it does is fill in group1 with all possible ordered subsequences of length 12. At that point, m = 0 and group = group1, so the call `Choose([?], 12, 1, group2)` is made (for every possible choice of group1, hence the `?`). That will choose all remaining ordered subsequences of length 12 for `group2`, at which point again m = 0 and now group = group2. We may now safely assign `group3` to the remaining entries (there is only one way to choose group3 after choosing group1 and group2).

We take ordered subsequences only by propagating the index at which to begin looking on the recursive call (`minIdx`). We take ordered subsequences to avoid getting permutations of the same set of 12 items (since order doesn't matter within a group).

Each recursive call to `Choose` in the loop passes `input` with one element removed: precisely that element that just got added to the group under consideration.

We check for `minIndex + m > n + 1` and stop the recursion early because, in this case, we have skipped too many items in the input to be able to ever fill up the current group with 12 items (while choosing the subsequence to be ordered).

You will notice I have hard-coded the assumption of 12/36/3 groups right into the logic of the program. This was done for brevity and clarity, not because you can't make parameterize it in the input size N and the number of groups k to form. To do this, you'd need to create an array of groups (k groups of size N/k each), then call `Choose` with N/k instead of 12 and use a select/switch case statement instead of if/then/else to determine whether to `Choose` again or print. But those details can be left as an exercise.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much !!